# Java Input won't recognize right key or down key

Tags: java, keyboard, lwjgl, slick2d

So I have just started using LWJGL with Slick2D and for some reason my code won't work for the right and down keys to move my player. However, the up and left keys do work. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException {


    Input input = gc.getInput();


    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        player.y -= (delta * 0.1f);
    } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        player.y += (delta * 0.1f);
    } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        player.x -= (delta * 0.1f);
    } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        player.x += (delta * 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the players position from integer to float and it now works.